# Insert variable into middle of url

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

how could I insert a variable into the middle of a URL using vb.net?

e.g.

```
Dim ver As String = "variable"

http://testurl.co.uk/folder/next_folder/" & ver & "/test.exe
```

(not sure if this is correct above)

Note: I know how to set a variable but not sure how to insert into the middle of a URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost, I think you want this:

```
Dim ver As String = "variable"
Dim url As String = "http://testurl.co.uk/folder/next_folder/" & ver & "/test.exe"
```

To browse the url in the form do something like this:

```
Dim wb1 As New Net.WebBrowser()

Form1.Controls.Add(wb1)
wb1.Navigate(url)
```

Comment: If `WebBrowser1` exists, then yes.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try and yes WebBrowser1 does exist

Answer (score 1):

You could do that (as @SysDragon has pointed out, you need to store the result in a variable).  Another alternative would be:

```
Dim ver As String = "variable"
Dim url As String = String.format("http://testurl.co.uk/folder/next_folder/{1}/test.exe", ver)
```

It probably doesn't matter for something as trivial as this, but strings are immutable, so doing:

```
Dim myString as String = "a" & "b" & "c"
```

effectively destroys and recreates the string twice.  `StringBuilder` (which I believe `string.format` uses internally) prevents this.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I try debug it says "**;**" is invalid

Comment: Sorry - me jumping from VB to C# and not removing the semi-colon!