# insert variable into middle of quotation/url

Tags: java

I need to insert a variable into the middle of a url using Java.

```
File f = new File("/home/james/YCSB/bin/100.dat");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) 
System.out.println("yes");
```

The 100 needs to be the variable here. For example, I would imagine the code looking something like this:

```
String v;
File f = new File[]("/home/james/YCSB/bin/"+v".dat");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) 
System.out.println("yes");
```

I am aware that there is question almost exactly like this:
[Insert variable into middle of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872754/insert-variable-into-middle-of-url)
However it is using .net.

Comment: Are you asking about how to concatenate strings?

Comment: So, your question is how to concatenate a string in Java?

Comment: Yes, wasn't aware of the correct name. I was missing an extra +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a + after the v. If you add it then your string should work fine.

```
File f = new File[]("/home/james/YCSB/bin/"+v+".dat");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatination

```
File f = new File("bal bla" + variable + "bla");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing + in string

**Try this:**

```
String v;
v = "100"; // dont forget
File f = new File[]("/home/james/YCSB/bin/"+v+".dat");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) 
System.out.println("yes");
```

**Everything separate**

```
 File f = new File[]("/home" + "/james" + "/YCSB" + "/bin/" + v +  ".dat");
```